# How to sell Android game if selling through Market is not available in your country

Tags: android

Android Market doesn’t allow developers from my country to sell app. From what I understand the only chance to make some profit is to place ads in my application.

Does ads make a decent profit or is there some other way to earn money are there any other payments system available for Android to bypass Google’s limitations?

Comment: You can change the country your google account is from. If you set it to be in lets say america or england it will be in english, but you will bypass the limitations

Answer (score 4):

You can use PayPal in some of the following ways:

- Generate a unique download url for your app that works for a limited time.
- Generate an unlock key that unlocks your free version.

[According to this article PayPal can already facilitate in-app purchases in some countries.](http://www.androidtapp.com/you-will-be-able-to-buy-android-apps-with-paypal/)  When this will become available outside of the mentioned I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YAAM](http://yaam.mobi), an alternative market, with Paypal paiement. Like the market, there is an application which manages update. For Moblox(our game) customers, it is very easy.

YAAM is an open source product, so you can developp your own Market if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I saw you sell Moblox on both AM and YAAM is it possible to share which sells more?

Comment: Android Market... But, Yaam is useful only for users, who can't buy it with google checkout. So that's not fair.

Answer (score 0):

An example that came to mind for the situation you described is how Rovio initially launched Angry Birds on android.  Angry Birds for android started by being available only on http://www.getjar.com/ with ad support in game.  Eventually they moved into the android market, as well, but the game was free either way in this case, so revenue would be coming through ads on the android side of things.

Comment: And a pretty decent ad revenue too: http://techcrunch.com/2010/12/03/angry-birds-android-1-million-advertising/ (1M USD/mo from ads in the android version)